# How to property type the MikroORM FindOneOrFailOptions parameter to collect it in advance

Tags: typescript, mikro-orm

I'm working on a typescript project and, at some point, I need to collect the `FindOneOrFailOptions` parameter from MikroORM in advance.

The code is far more complicated but I've managed to replicate the issue with fewer lines.

While this code works without a problem:

```js
class ProviderRepository {
   public async findOneByUrl(url: string): Promise<Provider> {
      const repository = /* is of type EntityRepository<Provider> */
      return await repository.findOneOrFail({ url }, { populate: ['profile'] });
    }
}
```

The following one fails by raising `TS2345: Argument of type '{ populate: string[]; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'FindOneOrFailOptions<Provider, string>'.`:

```js
class ProviderRepository {
   public async findOneByUrl(url: string): Promise<Provider> {
      const repository = /* is of type EntityRepository<Provider> */

      const options = { populate: ['profile'] };
      return await repository.findOneOrFail({ url }, options);
                                                     -------
    }
}
```

Well, sure enought the solution should be to declare `options` as `FindOneOrFailOptions<Provider, string>`. However, if I do this, then it raises `TS2322: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'.`:

```js
class ProviderRepository {
   public async findOneByUrl(url: string): Promise<Provider> {
      const repository = /* is of type EntityRepository<Provider> */

      const options: FindOneOrFailOptions<Provider, string> = { populate: ['profile'] };
                                                                           ---------
      return await repository.findOneOrFail({ url }, options);
    }
}
```

And at this point I'm a bit lost as how to proceed.
I presume the `never` in there comes from the function declaration:

```js
class EntityRepository<T extends AnyEntity<T>> {
    findOneOrFail<P extends string = never>(where: FilterQuery<T>, options?: FindOneOrFailOptions<T, P>): Promise<Loaded<T, P>>;
}
```

However even if I use this function like `repository.findOneOrFail<string>(...)` it still produces the same error.
I reckon there must be some sort of auto-casting as if I inline the parameter, even without the `<string>`, it happy takes it without a problem. This tells me that I have not nailed the exact type that it is expecting but I'm a bit clueless as per what this type could be.

How can I have the `options` parameter declared in advance without any issue? Many thanks!

Comment: You could try `const options: FindOneOrFailOptions<Provider, 'profile'> = { populate: ['profile'] };`

Comment: @tromgy good shout! It does work this way. However, the problem is that I want this parameter to be variable (I should have mentioned it).

Comment: Actually that gave me an idea. I've now tried with `keyof T` (the final code was a bit more complicated than the code I provided) and it still does not work: `TS2344: Type 'keyof T' does not satisfy the constraint 'string'.` but, `keyof T & string` seems to do the trick! It also validates that you input a valid property of `T` which is perfect!! Thanks so much!

Comment: Actually, not perfect as sometimes you want `'property.subproperty'` in the populate and this would make it fail. Goddamn it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can't be typed just to a `string`, if we allow that, we lost type safety as any string could be used. It needs to be string literal type with the actual values. For your specific use case, a const assertion should do the job:

```
await repository.findOneOrFail({ url }, { populate: ['profile'] as const });
```

> How can I have the options parameter declared in advance without any issue? Many thanks!

You can't really have it defined upfront and expect any kind of type safety as there is no connection with the actual value - you need to cast things yourself if you want that. Or set the type arg to `any`, not nice but in fact it is the most precise description of what you want, as it disables the strict types for populate hints. That is the only way to allow setting more populate hints after you create such object.

```
const options: FindOneOrFailOptions<Provider, any> = { populate: ['profile'] };
options.populate.push('otherProp');
```

If you just want to create the object and you know it will contain just one item, you can pass the type value explicitly.

```
const options: FindOneOrFailOptions<Provider, 'profile'> = { populate: ['profile'] };
```

If you don't provide the second type argument, the default is `never` - so without it you can never pass anything to the `populate` hint.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The `any` does indeed work. IMHO, this is not the place where you want to enforce pre-compilation type checks for 2 reasons: you might want to load deeper data by using `'property.subproperty'` syntax and, because it will anyway end into the DB, so you can rely on the DB to validate the schema. In my case, allowing any value without error was my goal (and `any` does the trick). Havin type checks is a nice to have for me. I've found that schema validation can be acomplished somehow with `keyof T & string` but this restricts deeper data loading. Thank you!

Comment: Its indeed not perfect, but I am not aware of better ways to have things work as they work right now. I will rather have strict types by default and force users to use casting in those cases, then have weak types (e.g. via `keyof T & string`).

Comment: But I am not sure what you are trying to tell me. Your example is a method that statically populates one relation. You do it inside the method definition. It is not dynamic = const assertion is the right solution. If you want things dynamic, you need the generic type argument defined in your method and passed down to the `FindOptions` type.

Comment: My example is a boiled down version of what I need. In my real code, the relations are dynamic so I cannot rely on having the name of the relation as a type parameter. In summary, what I needed was a way to shut typescript up and I would take responsibility for any bug on that decision. However, what I wanted to say is that, imho, ensuring type safety for the values of `populate` is a bit of an overkill as the DB will do it anyway and doing it in the code prevents from loading more complex structures. In a nutshell and imho, accepting `string[]` would suffice in here.

Comment: I can't really agree with that  ¯\_(ツ)_/¯